# WhileLoop through a mysql db list

Tags: php, mysql

Ok so long story short, I have a simple mailto function I want to apply/run for every name on a db list. Since it's not working, I removed all the mail stuff from it and to test to make sure the while loop was working with the db, did this

```
<?php 


$connect2db = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','pass','dbnamehere');
if(!$connect2db){
    die("Sorry but theres a connection to database error" . mysqli_error);
}

$sn_query = "SELECT * FROM email_list";

$sn_queryResult = mysqli_query($connect2db, $sn_query) or die("Sorry but theres a connection to database error" . mysqli_error);
$sn_rowSelect = mysqli_fetch_array($sn_queryResult);
$to = $sn_rowSelect;

?>

<br/><br/>
////lower part on page //////<br/><br/>


<?php
while($sn_rowSelect = mysqli_fetch_array($sn_queryResult) ) {
echo "hello there" . " " . $sn_rowSelect['firstname'] . " <br/>";
}
?>
```

Now this works, it goess through my db and prints out all my first names from the database list. In my noob brain, id think that if i remove the echo lines, and enter the appropriate mailto information, that it would loop just like before, but send mail to each name. so i did this:

```
<?php 
$sn_query = "SELECT email FROM email_list";

$sn_queryResult = mysqli_query($connect2db, $sn_query) or die("Sorry but theres a connection to database error" . mysqli_error);

$sn_rowSelect = mysqli_fetch_array($sn_queryResult);

$to = implode(",",$sn_rowSelect);
$from = $_POST['sender'];
$subject = $_POST['subj'];
$mssg = $_POST['message'];
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0rn";
$headers  .= "From: $from\r\n";
$mailstatus = mail($to, $subject, $mssg, $headers);

?>

<br/><br/>
//////////<br/><br/>


<?php
while($sn_rowSelect = mysqli_fetch_array($sn_queryResult) ) {
    $mailstatus;

    if($mailstatus) {
        echo "Success";
    }else{
        echo "There was a problem sending the mail. Check your code and make sure that the e-mail address $to is valid\n";
    }
}



?>
```

now this emails the first name on my list, but not the rest.
I don't get any errors so not sure what the problem is. I was going to try an if statement with `num_rows` but somewhere else, on StackOverflow, someone said that didn't help since the while loop took care of it by itself. (I tried it either way and it still emailed only the first name) I'm trying here but to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not called the `mail()` function inside your loop. You call it once outside.  Instead try something like the following.

Assuming you have retrieved the `$to` address from your database query (like you did with the firstname in testing), pull it from the rowset, and use it in `mail()`:

```
while($sn_rowSelect = mysqli_fetch_array($sn_queryResult) ) {

    // Get the $to address:
    $to = $sn_rowSelect['email'];

    // Call mail() inside the loop.
    $mailstatus = mail($to, $subject, $mssg, $headers);

    if($mailstatus) {
        echo "Success";
    }else{
        echo "There was a problem sending the mail. Check your code and make sure that the e-mail address $to is valid\n";
    }
}
```

Note also, that since you call `mysql_fetch_array()` at the top of your script, your while loop will start with the second row.  You should remove the first call to `mysql_fetch_array()` that occurs before the loop.

```
$sn_queryResult = mysqli_query($connect2db, $sn_query) or die("Sorry but theres a connection to database error" . mysqli_error);

// Don't want this...
//$sn_rowSelect = mysqli_fetch_array($sn_queryResult);
```

Comment: i dont know why, but it worked lol. thanks. As far as this line, " your while loop will start with the second row. You should remove the first call to mysql_fetch_array() that occurs before the loop." im not sure why but, im still a noob, ill figure it out laterlol, again, thanks